# Ambiguity between generic and simple string in params

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ambiguous-call

I have 2 methods, one of which works with generic param and other one with regular string. It looks like this :

```
public static async Task PostAlertAsync(this IQueueService queueService,
    AlertTypes alertType,
    string orgId, 
    AlertDetailsBase details = null)
{
    Guard.ArgumentNotNull(queueService, nameof(queueService));
    Guard.ArgumentNotNullOrEmptyString(orgId, nameof(orgId));

    var alertMessage = BuildAlertQueueMessage(alertType, orgId, details);
    await queueService.SendMessageAsync(alertMessage);
}

public static async Task PostAlertAsync<T>(this IQueueService queueService, 
    AlertTypes alertType, 
    T source,
    AlertDetailsBase details = null, 
    string customSubject = null)
    where T: IAlertSource
{
    Guard.ArgumentNotNull(queueService, nameof(queueService));
    Guard.ArgumentNotNull(source, nameof(source));

    var alertMessage = BuildAlertQueueMessage<T>(alertType, source, details, customSubject);
    await queueService.SendMessageAsync(alertMessage);
}
```

I wonder, why calling compiling next call result with ambiguity error? `String` in this case is obviously doesn't implement `IAlertSource`

```
QueueServiceCollection.Alerts.PostAlertAsync(AlertTypes.AzureAdDsProvisionCompleted, orgId);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You have default parameters. The compiler doesn't know which version of the method you are attempting to use defaults for.

Comment: @KennethK. yes, and also I have required params. Which in second method are not applicable to the call, because string is not IAlertSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: `where` restrictions are not used while determining which method overload is to be used. So when you ignore that information it becomes not obvious which overload to use. You might argue that exact mach is better but it is not. Both methods can be called using string as parameter if you disregard this information.

Comment: Related article by Eric Lippert: [Constraints are not part of the signature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/)

Comment: But why, if I get rid of optional parameters, it resolve correctly?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria its not about optional parameters its about generic type parameter and it is how they decided to implement it. As simple as someone decided its not worth the effort and complexity.

Comment: @Rafal maybe I lost something, but if you remove optional parameters from both method it resolve to the right overload.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria actually you are correct about the optional parameters (small surprise for me :)). Yet my answer stands I is just how they did it nothing more.